# ERROR: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose build works fine but if  try docker-compose up its failed with following Error Message:

```
ERROR: for identityserver  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 116, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 876, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 416, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 66, in parallel_execute
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
identityserver:
 build: ./IdentityServer
 dockerfile: ./dockerfile
 container_name: identityServer
 volumes:
   - ./:/app/
 environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMET=Development
 ports:
  - "5000:5000"
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app
Copy . .
RUN dotnet clean
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Docker version:

```
elds-MBP:dashboard eld$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
elds-MBP:dashboard eld$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

Operationsystem: macos

Comment: You've got an extra space in front of the volume list entry here: `- ./:/app/`

Comment: i corrected it but the error still exists

Comment: who is interested in a solution: I only reseted docker and in works again. it was no fault at the code